# Understanding OAuth and client sessions

Tags: oauth, twitter

I'm learning about OAuth with the goal of allowing visitors to my website the ability to sign in with Twitter. I've been using the Python based oauth2 library as a learning tool, and I think I get most of it.

I understand that after the user authenticates with the service (Twitter in this case) the user is sent to the callback URL with the parameters `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier`.

What I fail to understand is the proper way of storing this information in the users browser. How do I identify these values during subsequent requests? Am I required to create a session system as with a normal website, or is there some magic in OAuth that makes this unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you handle client sessions of people who visit your website is not covered by OAuth, that remains up to you (and the usual session management frameworks).

All OAuth does is tell you that the user really is the Twitter user he claims to be. You can then associate this piece of information with the user session on your site (just like you would if the login screen was on your own page).

Answer (score 1):

there are two types of `oauth_token` and `oauth_verifier` in twitter API

first is **request token** that always come different on each process, that can be save into session using `getRequestToken` method

i m telling in PHP view , but logic are same in any language
/

```
* Get request token */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save request token to session */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

another is **accesstoken:**  that is retrived via `getAccessToken` method

```
 $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

Array
(
    [oauth_token] => 223961574-mEctH7SHai######
    [oauth_token_secret] => G7Buyxn4okF31Ln3ulAh#####
    [user_id] => 223961574
    [screen_name] => ltweetl
)
```

these token are same  which is in your registered application on twitter

and already given at below page...

**http://dev.twitter.com/apps/{your_app_id}/my_token.**